# adding fields in SharePoint 2013 C#

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development

what is the different in adding a field and creating a field ?

```
SPFieldChoice category = (SPFieldChoice)list.Fields.CreateNewField(SPFieldType.Choice.ToString(), Constants.category);
```

or

```
SPFieldText fullname = (SPFieldText)list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(list.Fields.Add(Constants.fullName, SPFieldType.Text, false));
```

any difference in performance ?

Answer (score 1):

They are the same ways to create a new field for a list.You can reference here for the details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection_methods.aspx